# How to extract files server side on Amazon Cloud Drive?

Tags: zip, server-side, unzip, amazon-clouddrive

I have a a 17Gb zip file on Amazon Cloud Drive. Is there a way to unzip / extract it without downloading it first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this on the server end.